# How to create 5 spinner in the same activity android?

Tags: android, dropdown, android-spinner

I'm trying to create 5 dependent spinners in the same activity. I'm confused about how to do that. My spinners tree is like below

> - 1st spinner contains 2 independent items which I select
> - 2nd spinner contains 8 items but shows 4 items according to selection from 1st spinner
> - 3rd spinner contains 28 items but shows 3/4 item according to previous 2 selection
> - 4th and 5th spinner contain 128 and 800 items accordingly and show according to previous selection.

**My progress yet.**

I did only XML part of this as I don't understand how to resolve this. My XML is given below.

```
 <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
    android:id="@+id/region"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    app:hintText="Region" />

<com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
    android:id="@+id/district"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    app:hintText="District" />

<com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
    android:id="@+id/upz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    app:hintText="Upz" />

<com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
    android:id="@+id/union"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    app:hintText="Union" />

<com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
    android:id="@+id/village"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    app:hintText="Vill" />
```

So, Is there anyone who can help to figure out or help me to understand this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? your XML looks fine

Comment: I did the only XML....I'm confused about how to make them work in JAVA.

Comment: Okay, Firstly how are you getting the data you are going to display in the spinners?

Comment: I create 5 string array fir 5 spinners. After this, I got stuck about how to represent them.

Comment: Okay then you use ADAPTER to display the data in the spinners, ```SpinnerNAME.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(Activity,this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ARRAYNAME)``` this is an example but should help if you get stuck just search for how to make an adapter for spinners

Comment: I tried this, this just shows data in my spinner. now how to make them dependable one to another.

Comment: use onitemselect google it

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's the thing. Can't give the whole logic but I can give you a simple hint

Let's assume your `Region` and `District` data classes are like this

```kotlin
data class Region(val regionId:Int, regionName:String)
```

```kotlin
data class District(val districtId:Int, districtName:String, parentRegion:Int)
```

**Step 1**

First of all set your region spinner adapter which is independent of any other spinner

**Step 2**

Set your region spinner item selected listener, so that when one item is selected it triggers the generation of next spinner

```kotlin
regionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener { regionId ->
    // setup district spinner adapter here
}
```

**Step 3**

Set other spinner item selected listeners as done in previous step

```kotlin
districtSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener { districtId ->
    // setup other dependent spinner adapter here
}
```

Comment: I'm using array and what can be the logic for the district as the depend on the region?